# Problem with drawing commutative diagram using tikzcd inside onslide command in frame

Tags: beamer, overleaf, tikz-cd, presentations, commutative-diagrams

I have been trying to prepare a presentation for which I require a commutative diagram. Now I tried to use tikzcd to draw the diagram, but it didn't work properly. Here's the code:

```
    \begin{frame}{Smooth Structure on Manifolds}
        \onslide<1->{Let $(U,\varphi),\ (V,\psi)$ be two charts. If $U\cap V\neq \phi$, then define the map $\psi\circ \varphi^{-1}:\varphi(U\cap V)\to \psi(U\cap V)$, called the \textbf{transition map from $\varphi$ to $\psi$.}}
        \onslide<2->{We say that the charts $(U,\varphi),\ (V,\psi)$ are \textbf{smoothly compatible} if either $U\cap V = \phi$, or $\psi\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is a \textit{\underline{diffeomorphism}}.\\}
        \onslide<3->{\begin{tikzcd}
                        U\cap V \arrow[r, "\varphi"] \arrow[d, "psi"] 
                        & \varphi(U\cap V) \arrow[rd, "\psi\circ \varphi^{-1}"] \\ 
                         \psi(U\cap V) 
                    \end{tikzcd} \\}            
        \onslide<4->{A \textit{\underline{diffeomorphism}} is a smooth homeomorphism such that the inverse is also smooth.\\~\\}
    \end{frame}
```

The output is this:
[image]

Here is the list of errors:
[image]
How do I correct it? Please help.

How do I rectify this. Please help.

Comment: Specify `ampersand replacement=\&` in the options of the `tikzcd` environment (or globally, say `\tikzcdset{diagrams={ampersand replacement=\&}}` and use `\&` instead of `&`. Maybe the `onlyenv` environment with a `fragile` frame can be used without having to change the `&`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel using `ampersand replacement=\&` worked perfectly! What was the issue here though? Also, can you please tell me how to align this diagram centrally?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Never mind about central alignment. I aligned it centrally using `center` environment.